# No hyperlinks in doxygen-generated docu for imported base-classes

Tags: python, doxygen

(*I am not sure how to formulate this question in english. Feel free to edit my question please.*)

See the code below for more details.
I generate a html-documentation with a default (`doxygen -g`) doxygen configuration.

The inheritance tree is displayed correct for all classes here. I can click on `ABase` in the tree of `A`. But this is not possible in the tree for `B`.
I think this is because `B` import its base class from another module (`a.py`).

And when I look in the tree of `ABase` I only see `A` there but not `B`.

Is there a way to fix that?

The file `a.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
    classes of 
"""

class ABase:
    """
    bla
    """
    pass

class A(ABase):
    """
    bla
    """
    pass
```

The file `b.py`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from .a import ABase

class B(ABase):
    """
        bla
    """
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=726219) about parsing the `import` statement. This is fixed in doxygen 1.8.7 and higher.